# Disposing of database connection from within WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, attributes

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS:

```
[WebServiceLogging]
public class ComplaintService : IComplaintService
```

This service has the `WebServiceLogging` attribute that does straightforward request/response logging into the database:

```
public class WebServiceLoggingAttribute : Attribute, IServiceBehavior {
    SomeDatabaseConnection connection;        // unmanaged resource

    ... interface implementations

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase) {
        IDispatchMessageInspector messageInspector = new WebServiceLogger(connection, _operations);
        foreach (ChannelDispatcher dispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            foreach (EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher in dispatcher.Endpoints)
            {
                DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime = endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime;
                dispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(messageInspector);    // pass the logger into WCF.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Logging work is done from the `WebServiceLogger`, which uses the `SomeDatabaseConnection` unmanaged resource:

```
public class WebServiceLogger : IDispatchMessageInspector {
    public object AfterReceiveRequest {
        ... gather Request data.
    }
    public void BeforeSendReply {
        ... gather Request data.
        ... Log using ADO.NET
        ... Dispose of Command object. No Connection closing!
    }

}
```

I need to close the connection within `WebServiceLogger` once I'm done with logging. Options I've identified are:

1. Implement an `IDisposable` on `WebServiceLogging` class and do a `Dispose()` there or
2. Dispose of `SomeDatabaseConnection` directly from `WebServiceLogger.BeforeSendReply()`

My questions here are:

- `IDispatchMessageInspectors` (such as `WebServiceLogger`) passed into `dispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors` - I've noticed that this object is not recreated per each request, but rather only once on the first request towards my service. How are such objects disposed of? Does WCF call `Dispose()˙ on them or should I use some other approach here?
- Since we're at it, I have a nagging thought that perhaps using unmanaged resources in an `Attribute` is not such a good idea. Googling for `c# attribute dispose` didn't yield any results (there is one result on destructor, though). Any critiques on this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open and close a connection inside the `BeforeSendReply` method; i.e. make it a local variable (with a `using`-block, etc.).

Something like this:

```
public void BeforeSendReply {
    ... gather Request data.
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(...)) {
        ... Log using ADO.NET
    }
}
```

The overhead is usually irrelevant (as ADO.NET uses connection pooling and won't really open/close a brand new connection). Second, and most importantly, that way you don't have to think about how your interceptor instance is used/called in a multithreaded (parallel requests) scenario.

That also matches better the unit of work pattern, that would be typically used if you did the same thing in the implementation method of an OperationContract. If you think about it, the interceptor points (`AfterReceiveRequest` and `BeforeSendReply`) are really just extensions of such method implementations (kind of AOP).

Comment: We went down this route prior to your answer. I'm selecting this as the accepted. What literature would you recommend for discovering more about how ASP.NET handles connections?

Comment: The only book I've read about this (WCF, not ASP.NET in particular) was "Programming WCF Services". Other than that mostly googling, blogs, etc.